# Error when running on a phone, while it works on the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Why is that whenever I run it on the Android Emulator, it runs perfectly, yet when I running it on my android phone, it forced to stop or goes into error?

Result in Android Emulator: (Expected Result)

[image]

Result in an android phone:

[image]

Comment: check your logcat or run it in debug mode

Comment: @AnisurRahmanTonu it already runs yet it doesn't have the same result when running on android emulator and running on android phone

Comment: run it on debug mode ..i think you will get the error

Comment: that's wrong part of logcat

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the SDK pointer. Probably, use the SDK of android 8 in a phone with android 7, cause crash. I develop one app that usually crash in android 5 but works perfectly in android 7 (.1) and 8 (.1). Just change the SDK target.